# MailScheduler for JSP and Servlets

Tags: multithreading, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

i have a web application which has a time tracker function.
The time tracker function is used to send an email at a later date based on the inputted date in the database.

I would like to ask for any ideas on how to implement this using JSP and Servlets.

How do i create a "listening" thread in the server side that constantly checks the database
for the time tracker function?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [Quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) to wake-up every minute or so and send mails. You can see how to get this work with servlets in another [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905671/email-notifications-and-reminders-in-java-web-app-using-quartz-scheduler/4905734#4905734).